# Is the SharePoint build machine capable of running web services?

Tags: 2007, web-services

I created a program that updates list items using the Lists web services.  It works on my machine and other machine, but it does not work on the SharePoint build machine where it will become an automated process.  I do not have access to test on the SharePoint build machine, I must send my programs to the administrator and he tries it.

Is the build machine capable of running web services?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the build machine?  Is it running IIS?  Is it in the SharePoint farm?

Comment: I tried to say the actual single machine that is running SharePoint, IIS, Windows Server, SQL Server, and everything.  We have a single machine farm.

Comment: Do you have an actual error message?

Comment: Sorry sange but I've had to downvote because of the lack of details and info in your question. Without some clues to go on then none of the answers can be little more than guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you disable the loopback check, so that the build server can make connections to itself

```
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa -Name "DisableLoopbackCheck" -Value "1" -PropertyType dword
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642/en-us

Comment: It was the loopback setting.  We set this on the test machine and it worked so we will be redoing the program to not need the loopback setting.

Comment: Eh? You can't redo the program to not need the loopback setting if you're relying on NT Authentication. Its a fundamental part to get NT authentication working.

Answer (score 2):

If WSS or MOSS is installed, then the machine is capable or running web services.

Assuming that your build machine does have SharePoint installed, then is there a web application / site collection created on it? Are you accessing the web services using a URL? If so, does the URL of that site collection exist on the build machine?

If you have code that runs against the list web service for example, your code will try to access http://sitecollection/_vti_bin/lists.asmx

If the site collection doesn't exist, then your code won't run.

If that doesn't answer your question, could you please give more details on the build machine?

Comment: Not true.  I have worked on several projects where the build machine did not even have IIS installed, let alone SharePoint.  All required SharePoint DLLs were copied to a specific folder on the machine and then used in the build.

Comment: Yeah, it's not really what I meant to say. If WSS/MOSS is installed, then the web services can run is more like it. Edited my answer thanks!

Comment: You don't need the SharePoint DLLs at all if you are only using SharePoint web services.

Comment: Well yes you do if it's SharePoint code. Your visual studio project will reference at least Microsoft.SharePoint.dll If that file isn't on the build machine your project won't build...

Comment: I think we are just talking about two different things. In order to talk to the SharePoint web services (ex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx), you do **NOT** need SharePoint DLLs; you're just creating a service reference and communicating via SOAP. If you use the SharePoint API (ex: SPSite, SPWeb), then you **do** need the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- The build machine needs .NET installed (at least the version you targeted in Visual Studio)
- Validate permissions: The account that is running the app on the build machine needs to have access to the list and the site it is updating (sounds like at least Contribute rights)